# Ошибки при указании пути к аплету

Tags: java

Запускаю файл index.html (содержимое которого ниже) и выдаётся ошибка( которая тоже ниже). Я так понимаю, ошибка в пути к классу апплета. Сам файл index.html содержится в папке classes, а MouseApplet.class в classes\swinggraphiceditor, как показано на рисунках ниже.

[снимок http://i046.radikal.ru/1107/3d/e6123b43d29c.png](http://i046.radikal.ru/1107/3d/e6123b43d29c.png)

и

[image: снимок]

Содержимое файла index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Редактор</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Редактор ололо!</p>
        <applet code="MouseApplet.class" codebase="swinggraphiceditor"
          width="200" height="100">
        </applet>
    <body>
</html>
```

консоль выдаёт ошибку:

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MouseApplet (wrong name: swinggraphiceditor/MouseApplet)`
> `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`
> `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)`
> `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)`
> `at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)`
> `at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)`
> `at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)`
> `at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)`
> `at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)`
> `at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)`
> `at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)`
> `at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)`
> `at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)`
> `at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
> `Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MouseApplet (wrong name: swinggraphiceditor/MouseApplet)`

Как мне решить эту проблему? Ведь я правильно прописал атрибут `codebase="swinggraphiceditor"`. Если написать `code="swinggraphiceditor.MouseApplet.class"`, то всё нормально запустится и будет работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аттрибут `codebase` определяет путь к классам апплета без учета пакетов (так как иначе невозможно было бы указать правильное имя класса) Т.е. если бы ваш index.html находился уровнем выше, то нужно было бы указать `codebase=classes`. Аттрибут `code`, в свою очередь, определяет полное имя класса, с учетом пакетов.

Comment: спасибо вечером проверю, отпишусь